# How relevant is for a user the amount or batch of results shown?

Tags: gui-design, search-results, pagination

In a scenario with for a specific search, a preliminary design has been paginated in large batches of around 300 results and, besides showing the number of results obtained, it also showed the range of items being offered in the current page.

For example, it currently says:

301 to 600 of 1163 Results - [Search term]

in one line. I am redesigning it when I started doubting about how important it is to tell the user about the actual batch. Should we just say Previous and Next? Regular pagination (1, 2, 3,...)?

[image: This example is (obviously) not the final design, but a way of showing what I mean. Fig.1 specifies the batch, Fig.2 doesn't.]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Page numbering and batch numbers are used as navigational marks and orientation means in the information space of results.

This kind of awarenes is very important for users, as it used not only for supporting mental model of the information space, but also used for decision making.

**In physical world** this awarenes is frequently integrated in artifacts itself. For example, opened book gives cue of the current state with stack of pages, as shown: 
[image]
On maps special sign is used:
[image]

**In UI world** this task is implemented with progress indicators, scroll bars, step numbering (i.e. 2 of 4), etc., including batch numbering.

Comment: Hi @AlexeyKolchenko. Wouldn't that be more of a pagination concern? There is value in knowing what page you are in, but "showing 1-300 of 1,000 results" might not be as relevant to the user.


To follow your physical example, in a book you can sometimes see the name of the chapter, but that IS relevant. In some dictionaries, you can see from what result to what result you can find in a particular page. Those two are also good indicators of where the user is at, providing actual information. However, wouldn't my question's equivalent be to show "Chapter 5 (pages from 101 to 150)"?

Comment: @EdGG I'd say both Pagination and Batch numbering are the sides of one coin. Close aims, but different implementations. Still, having total numbers of results, it's more easy to orient with numbers (1-100 of 1000), than with pages (Page 1 of 1000 items?). Because former option uses same measurement unit, while latter (page vs items) are hard to compare. Butch numbering is close to scrollbar concept without graphical representation.